# No space left on device even after adding a Persistence Storage on gcloud

Tags: linux, debian, google-compute-engine

I am new to Google Cloud. I was downloaded a few text files into the VM instance. I then suddenly started getting messages like

```
bash: cannot create temp file for here-document: No space left on device
```

I ran the df -h and found that my disk was being used 100%

```
/dev/sdb        9.8G  9.3G     0 100% /
```

I searched about it and figured that I might need to add more persistence storage.

I followed the instructions here -> https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk

Now when I run the ***df -h*** I see that the new storage is added (usage is 1%)

```
/dev/sdc         20G   45M   20G   1% /mnt/disks/disk2
```

When I run ***lsblk***, I get:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0  10G  0 disk 
└─sda1   8:1    0  10G  0 part /
sdc      8:32   0  20G  0 disk /mnt/disks/disk2
```

However, I am still getting the same error with No space left on device. I have restarted the VM. Kindly help.

P.S.  VM -> Debian 4.9.65-3+deb9u2 (2018-01-04) x86_64

Comment: You've added a new disk rather than increasing the size of your existing one, so your root partition is still full.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I agreed with [roaima](https://serverfault.com/users/267016/roaima), you need to [increase the size of your existing boot disk](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#resize_pd) to solve this issue. After you resize the disk, you must [resize the file system](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/disks/add-persistent-disk#resize_partitions) so that the operating system can access the additional space. Boot disks use MBR partitions, which are limited to 2 TB in size. Do not resize boot disks beyond 2 TB.

Answer (score 1):

When creating a new instance (and new attached boot disk), you need to change the `--boot-disk-size` option, e.g. `gcloud compute --project "seekwell-scheduler-183021" instances create "myapp" --boot-disk-size "500GB"`.

If you can't SSH into the machine (bc of a timeout due to no space left), I know this sounds dumb, but you can just Stop the machine in the web UI and start it again.